# SQL: sum of all columns in only one query using UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, sql-update

I got this assignment at the university. My task is to fill in the new (not existing yet) column of my table with values: col1 + col2 + col3, using **only one query** based on operator **UPDATE** in MySQL.
As the result I will have table with 4 columns (col1, col2, col3, sum_of_columns).

And how can I do that, if UPDATE modifies only existing rows?

Comment: Can you show the effort that you tried so far?

Comment: Poor task. You should not store computed values like that. Will typically lead to data inconsistency. Create a view instead, or at least use triggers to manage the sum column.

Comment: You might look for a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new column is always the Sum of the three columns you can do this

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN `sum_of_columns` INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (col1+col2+col3) STORED NULL;
```

This would be the DEFAULT VALUE.

When you insert a row, this would  would be added when you add NULL as column 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE sample_table set col4 = col1+col2+col3 ;
```

In create table statement, you can set default value as NULL for col4 column.

Comment: Table is already created without 4th column and adding new column will require a second query which is violating the conditions of the task